# Retrieving all markers for Google Map (not just the current logged in user)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Google Map in which all markers are to be publicly available.  Only authenticated/logged in users can write markers and associated info to the DB.

My understanding is that the rules below will allow anyone to read the `mapinfo` route and only logged in users can write to it and that's what I want.

```
"mapinfo":{
     ".read" : true,
    "$user_id": {
          ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
    },
},
```

When I try to read from the database with the authenticated user, I only get the authenticated user's markers (as expected):

```
var mapitems = firebase.database().ref('mapinfo/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
```

I thought if I remove the current authenticated user from the route, then I would retrieve all the markers:

```
var mapitems = firebase.database().ref('mapinfo/');
```

This is returning the results, but not in the expected data structures.

How can I return all these results?  Is it possible to say something like this:

```
var mapitems = firebase.database().ref('mapinfo/[ANY-USER]');
```

Comment: Most likely you have a mistake in the way you're processing the list of results. Please share the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which in this case would include how you process the list (just logging the info is fine if that reproduces the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this by iterating over `snapshop.val()` and pushing the value, which is an object, on to the `mapInfoItems` array.

```
    var mapitems = firebase.database().ref('mapinfo/');
    mapitems.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
        $.each(snapshot.val(), function(key, value) {
            mapInfoItems.push(value);
            deferred.resolve(mapInfoItems);
        });
    });
```